# What's the equivalent of Entity.all(keys_only=True).fetch(20) in NDB?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

How do I get the equivalent result of the following query in NDB?

```
Entity.all(keys_only=True).fetch(20)
```

I know you can pass `'keys_only=True'` to the `iter()` method. But what if I want to perform a keys only fetch, how do I do that in NDB?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found it in the [GAE NDB Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass). The answer is `Entity.query().fetch(20,keys_only=True)`.

Comment: Also check the "cheat sheet": https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/edit?pli=1 -- It is really a conversion guide from db to ndb.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for this! It took me a while to find the solution in the official docs, and it's not the same implementation as DB. Perhaps this could also be added to the cheat sheet. :)