# GAE test to verify that ndb entity was **not** put in the datastore

Tags: unit-testing, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Very simply, I want to run some code and verify that **no entities** of kind `MyEntity(ndb.Model)` were put the datastore.

I've tried doing `MyEntity.query().fetch(keys_only=True)`, but that doesn't seem to be strongly-consistent (i.e. it doesn't show the one entity I just added), so returning an empty list is not true confirmation. (I should add that I'm using the `testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub` and I've tried `datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=1)` and `MasterSlaveConsistencyPolicy()` with no success.)

I thought there was a way to do a strongly-consistent 'get' for all keys of a kind, but now I can't find any documentation to support that.

I know that I can do a strongly-consistent get if I have a Key, but how would that translate to verification that an entity was **not** added, so there is no key to get?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I finally got it to work by [disabling the ndb cache via global context](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache) (tipped off by [How to Clear/Invalidate NDB Cache in Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565725/how-to-clear-invalidate-ndb-cache-in-tests)) in addition to the [normal unit testing testbeds](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting).

Also helped by:

- [What's the equivalent of Entity.all(keys_only=True).fetch(20) in NDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10203874/whats-the-equivalent-of-entity-allkeys-only-true-fetch20-in-ndb)
- [How to fetch the latest data in GAE Python NDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494726/how-to-fetch-the-latest-data-in-gae-python-ndb)

#### Helper Mixin:

```
class NdbTestbedNoCachingStronglyConsistentMixin(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()
        self.testbed.activate()
        policy = None
        # policy = datastore_stub_util.MasterSlaveConsistencyPolicy()
        # policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=1.0)
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(consistency_policy=policy)
        # self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()

        # It's not enough (or necessary) to use stubs for datastore and memcache -
        # we also need to change ndb policy to ensure that datastore queries
        # are strongly-consistent
        cxt = ndb.get_context()

        def disallow(*args, **kwargs):
            return False

        cxt.set_cache_policy(disallow)
        cxt.set_memcache_policy(disallow)
        super(NdbTestbedNoCachingStronglyConsistentMixin, self).setUp()

    def tearDown(self):
        super(NdbTestbedNoCachingStronglyConsistentMixin, self).tearDown()
        self.testbed.deactivate()
```

#### With usage like this (some irrelevant code left out):

```
def _get_entity_keys():
    return MyNdbEntity.query().fetch(keys_only=True)


class TestMyEntity(NdbTestbedNoCachingStronglyConsistentMixin):

    def tearDown(self):
        super(TestMyEntity, self).tearDown()

        # Verify our assumptions that no entities persist between tests
        assert MyNdbEntity.get_by_identifier(self.account, TEST_IDENTIFIER) is None
        assert not _get_entity_keys()

    def test_get_uri_should_retrieve_existing_entity(self):
        provider.get_uri(TEST_IDENTIFIER)  # creates entity
        all_assets_keys = _get_entity_keys()
        created_asset = MyNdbEntity.get_by_identifier(self.account, TEST_IDENTIFIER)

        self.assertIn(created_asset.key, all_assets_keys)

        provider.get_uri(TEST_IDENTIFIER)
        all_assets_keys_after_get = _get_entity_keys()

        self.assertSequenceEqual(all_assets_keys_after_get, all_assets_keys)


    def test_get_uri_should_create_entity_and_prefix_identifier_with_security_id(self):
        expected_identifier = TEST_SECURITY_ID + '-' + TEST_IDENTIFIER
        expected_uri = VIEWER_IMAGE_BASE_URI % expected_identifier

        uri = provider.get_uri(TEST_IDENTIFIER)
        image = _get_entity_keys()[0].get()

        self.assertEqual(image.identifier, expected_identifier)
        self.assertEqual(uri, expected_uri)
```

Comment: Is that the "correct" way to go, @guido-van-rossum?